# Cómo obtener último día del actual mes en android

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin

Estoy tratando de obtener el último día del mes, pero siempre me retorna 31 independientemente de la fecha que se establezca, se esta utilizando Calendar para el formato de la fecha, por ejemplo, este mes de abril cuenta con 30 días, pero me está retornado 31 días, lo cual no tiene sentido y cuando se tiene un mes de 31 días como marzo, retorna 30 días, cómo puedo solucionar esto?

```
now = Calendar.getInstance();
fech_aux = now;
day_first = fech_aux.getMinimum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
day_last = fech_aux.getMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
```

Para este caso me retorna lo siguiente:

```
day_first ==> 1
day_last ==> 31
```

Para day_last tendría que ser 30 no 31 para el presente mes, cómo puedo solucionar esto?

Comment: Es que `getMaximum()` devuelve precisamente lo que dice... el máximo valor de un campo (en este caso, de un campo DAY_OF_MONTH, que obviamente es 31, porque ningún mes tiene 32, si no sería 32!). Si lo que quieres es obtener el mayor día de una fecha determinada, deberías usar `fech_aux.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)`

Comment: Hola Jhony Luis, podrias decir si las respuestas dadas te resultaron utiles, gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int ultimoDia = Calendar.getInstance().getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
System.out.println(ultimoDia);
```

Aquí utilizas la **clase Calendar** para obtener el último día del mes en curso, el valor devuelto es almacenado en la **variable ultimoDia**, y finalmente imprimes el resultado.

Para usar la **clase Calendar** debes hacer la siguiente importación:

```
import java.util.Calendar;
```

Answer (score 1):

Si tienes java 8+, puedes usar la librería [TemporalAdjusters](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/TemporalAdjusters.html)

por ejemplo:

```
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.temporal.TemporalAdjusters;

LocalDate now = LocalDate.now(); // 2022-04-28
LocalDate lastDay = now.with(TemporalAdjusters.lastDayOfMonth()); // 2022-04-30
```